# Getting my numeric value of two months ago and attaching it to a string

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to get this date:

```
 oldDate2 = MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -2, Date)), True)
```

which as of today June 13, returns me Apr; to return me just the numeric value for April, i.e."4". is this possible?

Comment: Remove the `MonthName` part `Month(DateAdd("m", -2, Date))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
Month(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -2))
```